# Differential amplifier with active load Sedra Smith

Tags: amplifier, differential, load, active-components

I'm studing differential amplifiers on Sedra Smith book, and I have come across the following circuit. [image]

My question is: how can NMOS transistor \$Q_2\$ have a current \$g_{m2}\cdot v_{id}/2\$ if the voltage between its drain and source is zero? Now, I understand that this circuit is the equivalent circuit for small differential input signal. Thus, \$g_{m2}\cdot v_{id}/2\$ is a decrement component in the drain current rather than a real current going from source to drain. Still, I cannot understand why \$Q_2\$ isn't cut off with \$V_{ds}=0\$.

Comment: Transistor Q4 too for that matter...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Still, I cannot understand why Q2 isn't cut off with Vds=0.

It's clear that both schematics are AC circuit representaions since all supply voltages have been replaced with AC grounds, i.e, there are no DC sources, voltages or currents present - these have been *hidden* but not assumed to be zero.

So, in these circuits, we're only considering the *variations* of voltages and currents about their *quiescent* values.

Remember, the AC small-signal model and approximation is valid only if the transistors are *not* cut-off.  Indeed, it is assumed that the signal voltages and currents are *small* compared to the quiescent voltages and currents.

In the schematic on the right hand side, the fact that \$v_{ds2} = 0\$ simply means that the *total* voltage \$v_{DS2} = V_{DS2} + v_{ds2}\$ is *constant*, i.e., there is no AC small-signal voltage present, only the quiescent voltage \$V_{DS2}\$.

---

*In the above, I follow the convention that the *total* signal is lower-case variable with upper-case subscript, the *quiescent* value is upper-case variable with upper-case subscript, and the *(small)-signal* value is lower-case variable with lower-case subscript.  Thus, for example:

$$v_A = V_A + v_a $$

where \$v_A\$ is the total voltage, \$V_A\$ is the quiescent voltage and \$v_a\$ is the (small-)signal voltage.